# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "я" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> В ниже прикреплённых фотографиях, я рассказал о своем пути в среднем
> профессиональном образовании, вспомнив лучшие моменты и события.

Answer (score 2):

***В ниже прикреплённых фотографиях** // я рассказал о своем пути в среднем профессиональном образовании, вспомнив лучшие моменты и события.*

Обстоятельства, выраженные **падежной формой** существительного, в начале предложения обычно не обособляются, хотя небольшая **произносительная пауза** присутствует.

Обособление в таких случаях **возможно** для распространенных обстоятельств с производными предлогами (вследствие и др.), если требуется их особое выделение (подчеркивание).

**Примечание**

В сочетании "*в **нИже** прикреплённых фотографиях*" для наречия "ниже" изменена позиция. Это возможно, если нам нужно выделить наречие **ударением**. Допустим, есть разные серии фотографий, расположенных выше или ниже.

Но если этого не требуется, то лучше использовать нормальную позицию наречия: *в прикреплённых **ниже** фотогрАфиях.*

Измененная позиция наречия используется также **в терминах**: *вечнозеленый, малораспространенный* (их существование проверяется по словарю). Например: [малораспространенный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)